# If (isset $_Post[]) doesn't work when i send a var from ajax to php

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, bootstrap-4

I have a problem when am trying to catch the AJAX post into my PHP code

let me explain:

So what I want to do is that when the value change on `select2` I'll catch the result to send it at my PHP and then I want to use it in my db request .

To see if it works I've wrote a script to change the value of my input text when I've got a result from the post here is my codes:
Js script:

```
$(function(){
    $('#Refva').select2();
})

function changeValue(){
    var txt =  (document.getElementById('Refva'));

    $.ajax({
        url : "Vente.php",
        type : "POST",
        data : ({'txt':txt}),
        success: function(data){
            console.log(txt);
        },
        error : function(data){
            console.log("Une erreur s'est produite");
        }
    });
}
```

Php :

```
if (isset($_POST['txt']))
{
    $P = 'It work!';
}
```

Php script to fill the input :

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    var P = <?php echo json_encode($P); ?>;

    $('#Article_vendua').on('click',function(){
        $('#Article_vendua').val(P);
    });
});
</script>
```

When i use :

```
if (!isset($_POST['txt']))
{
  $P = 'It work!';
}
```

[image]

I have result! It's logical, but when I want to set isset it doesn't work

N.B. in my console I have the Post but not in my PHP

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting, for future reference.

Answer (score 0):

Try sending only the value of the select element and the whole object:

```
document.getElementById ('Refva'). value ()
```

Comment: still not working :/ i dont know where is the issu

Answer (score 0):

var txt =  (document.getElementById('Refva'));

> on the above : the **txt** holds the element not value
> you can use $('#Refva').val();

```
$.ajax({
    url : "Vente.php",
    type : "POST",
    data : ({'txt':txt}),  // brackets ( ) are not required here
    success: function(data){
        console.log(txt); // you should check the data - i dont know why to check txt
    },
    error : function(data){
        console.log("Une erreur s'est produite");
    }
});
```

Comment: humm the value is not the probleme the problem is when i try to catch the value with the if (isset($_Post[txt]))